# Adding a quantity to Magento Custom Options

Tags: php, custom

I've hit a bit of a brick wall. I'm wondering if there is a way to replicate what this website does in terms of entering text in a field and stating the quantity that you desire:

https://www.fastkeys.co.uk/keys/man/LOWE+AND+FLETCHER/201-400/592

Where it stats: 'Add more keys from this range.'

Is there any clear-cut way to do this in Magento?

Comment: That looks like suitable for grouped product with some customization in view part.

Comment: I see, what features should I be using in the grouped product?